# What recent (since 2014) work is there on the origin of the Indo-European 1st person singular nominative ego (etc.)?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, indo-european, proto-germanic, reconstruction

I  have an article by Hamp from 2011 and one by Blažek from 2014, but need to know if there is anything more recent, so I can cite it in an article that needs to be finished yesterday.

Comment: I PIE: eghom PA: i-ka-u Chukchi: e-ɣә-mi

We PA: i-ka-mi

Thou Chukchi: e-ɣә-tu PA: i-ka-su

Comment: Thank you and I can see that some years ago someone named Sir Cornflakes claimed such a relationship and moreover seemed to be saying that the proof of a connection between IE and CK was just these pronouns.  But he used passives like "is considered".  Would it be too much to ask for specific references to who has claimed this and where?

Comment: I asked this question in 2015: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12402/is-austronesian-the-closest-relative-to-pie

Comment: This also may be relevant for wider comparison: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47389/could-it-be-that-the-pronoun-e%c7%b5h%e2%82%82om-i-in-pie-is-not-an-innovation

Comment: I found discussions in russian, with you as a leading participant, and while they are a bit unclear, it appears that Bengtson is the (usual) suspect identified there.  In case you care (or anyone else), I am about to publish (and have already been showing to people) an IE-internal etymology of the words, and I wanted just to acknowledge any ideas that there might be out there, good or bad (not for me to judge).

Comment: Are you interested only in pronouns or other words as well? I also would be interested to tale a look on your paper.

Comment: For now it seems to me that not only PIE but even older stages of the language had two first person singular pronouns: *aini-gV and *min. The first one it seems was a compound that could form a wider paradigm and pronouns for other persons and numbers.

Comment: You may find this post useful: https://www.reddit.com/user/Anuclano/comments/15lo1f8/parallels_between_eurasiatic_indopacific_and/ Notice that I reconstruct the ancient *kʷet- "fit together, pair" and a root for "two", *đwor-. So, I think, the PIE word for "four", *kʷetwores, comes from kʷet+dwor. "Pair of twos". I also cosider the enclitic -kʷe to be coming from the same root (Burushaski has similar enclitic -kaa(t), Mapucho -ka). I think Burushaski, Mapucho are closely related to Eurasiatic (compare the word for tongue: PIE dn̥ǵʰwéh₂s Burush yuŋus Mapucho ðungu (language), Tiwi tingawa (lip)

Comment: I think, there were two roots meaning "tongue": ~*dungw and ~*tkeln, the both reflected in Eurasiatic.

Comment: Maybe one day. For now I just need the 'I' word and I have traced the idea.

Comment: Please let me know once the paper is available

Comment: You won't like (LOL) it but I will.  Thank you.